# What is the easiest way to get the loss history from a .tfevents file?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard, loss-function, tfrecord

I'm training a Tensorflow model making use of the TF ODA, `object_detection.model_lib_v2.train_loop`. This function creates a `.tfevents` file that can be red with Tensorboard.

Tensorboard prints graphs regarding the evolution of the loss/mAP of a training by reading this file. I want to be able to read it so that I can make a graph of the evolution of the loss with another library (MLFlow in this case).

Which is the simplest way to output the evolution of the loss as a list from this file? I'm using Python 3.9.

Thanks!